# how can i apply sorting in string in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

this is my sample document

```
{
  "string" : "class.chapter.1.topic.10"
}
```

how can I sort this string according to "chapter.anynumber.topic.anynumber"

Comment: will the string always start with "class." or are you trying to chop off everything up to the first dot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly scientific, but here is one way:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      string: "$string",
      chapter_num: {
        "$toInt": {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            {
              $split: [
                "$string",
                "."
              ]
            },
            2
          ]
        }
      },
      topic_num: {
        "$toInt": {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            {
              $split: [
                "$string",
                "."
              ]
            },
            4
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      chapter_num: 1,
      topic_num: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      string: "$string"
    }
  }
])
```

What it does is split the string by `.`, then grab elements 2 and 4 as `chapter_num` and `topic_num` of the resulting array, convert them to Int and sort it with:

```
  {
    $sort: {
      chapter_num: 1,
      topic_num: 1
    }
  }
```

toggle between `1` and `-1` to go asc or desc.

Note that this assumes that your string will adhere to this format: `xxx.xxx.num.xxx.num`.

If used against this sample collection:

```
[
  {
    "string": "class.chapter.1.topic.10"
  },
  {
    "string": "class.chapter.2.topic.3"
  },
  {
    "string": "class.chapter.1.topic.12"
  },
  {
    "string": "class.chapter.1.topic.1"
  }
]
```

The result will be:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
    "string": "class.chapter.1.topic.1"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "string": "class.chapter.1.topic.10"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "string": "class.chapter.1.topic.12"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "string": "class.chapter.2.topic.3"
  }
]
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/6-2QRIppu0u